# MSBuild weird behavior when run inside a script

Tags: powershell, msbuild

I have some PS scripts that I use for SVN tagging / releasing applications.

Usually its working fine, everything is built as I want to.
Few days ago, I'm told to make a fresh release of some older application.

So I tried leveraging my scripts for that purpose. So far so good.
The problem I'm facing now: Somehow, when MSBuild is called inside my script, its giving me errors

The thing is, when I execute the same command outside the script in a PS console, its building without errors.

[image: my console outputs]

The call: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\msbuild.exe solution.sln /t:Build /p:Configuration=Release /m /v:q /clp:Summary /nologo`

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it has to do with PackageReference on older projects..
https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/8100 my workaround is to build in VS first then use my script without restore or clean.

So I got my release.